# BackgroundWorker and ManualResetEvent

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, manualresetevent

The task.

I have one method which runs two long-time functions inside.

Im not talking about locking objects here. These funcs are independent, only have same parameter which used in readonly.

I want one func to run inside thread.

```
private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private Result result;

{
 BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
 bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
 bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
 bw.RunWorkerAsync(new BackgroundWorkerArgument(bitmap, image));

Rectangle rectangle = DetectRectangle(bitmapClone));
mre.WaitOne();
mre.Reset();

<another code, dont bother>
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result= (Result)e.Result;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorkerArgument argument = (BackgroundWorkerArgument)e.Argument;
        e.Result = CreateResult(argument.Bitmap, argument.Image);
        mre.Set();
    }
```

The problem.

`<another code, dont bother>` runs immediately after i do `Set()`. Its ok.

But `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` runs after that. This means result variable has null, but i want it contains the result of thread's function.

How to rework my code - `result= (Result)e.Result` must runs before next line to `WaitOne()` ?

If its not possible with `BackgroundWorker` maybe i need to use threads ? 
I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Why are you using a `BackgroundWorker` if you're blocking your thread with `ManualResetEvent.WaitOut`?  You're missing the point of `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` tells you when the BGW is done, just do "<another code, dont bother>" in there...

Comment: I just want to separate two functions to win about 10seconds. The results of both functions are used in the next code, so i cant go it without both functions completed

Comment: "win about 10seconds"?  Win what?

Comment: One func takes about 8 secs to run. Another - 10sec. 10+8=18 secs in main thread. I want to run 8 in main thread, and 10 in the another. so general process should be faster.

Comment: So i really think maybe BackgroundWorker is not the solution because RunWorkerCompleted runs in main thread and no guarantee it will run before another code in main thread.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of BGW

Comment: ok, can you please show me the example how to run thread with parameters and return the result ?

Comment: if this isn't the question you want to ask, close it and ask another.